# build search query from a dict?

Tags: python, tinydb

let say I have dict { k1 : v1, k2 : v2 }, how do I build query from this.
I can not do directly :

```
.search( (Query().k1 == v1) & (Query().k2 == v2))
```

because the dict may also be :

```
{k2:v2} OR {k1:v1, k3:v3} OR ........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search() function on an instance of TinyDB actually takes a predicate as an argument, and instances of Query create these predicates behind the scenes. To run a more advanced search, you can supply TinyDB with your own predicate.

```
from tinydb import Query,TinyDB

def predicate(obj,requirements):
    for k,v in requirements.items():
        if k not in obj or obj[k]!=v:
            return False
    return True

tiny = TinyDB('db.json')

requirements={
    'a':1,
    'b':3
}

print(tiny.search(lambda obj: predicate(obj,requirements)))
```